# Как на React создать систему расширяемую плагинами?

Tags: reactjs, архитектура, typescript, плагин

У меня есть `React` сайт на `TypeScript`.

На стороне сервера `ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC`, но как делать плагинную систему на ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC это отдельная тема, и в этом вопросе её не трогаю.

Мне необходимо позволить программистам писать плагины для сайта. Как это можно сделать, какие для этого есть подходы и библиотеки / фреймворки?

Например у меня на форуме есть компонент сообщение форума, я хочу написать плагин который мне на это сообщение добавит возможность лайкать. Допустим со стороны сервера всё подготовлено, как мне на клиенте внедрить дополнительную логику в уже имеющийся компонент, или даже целиком полностью подменить компонент сообщения?

Я понимаю что отдельная проблема это не допускать вредоносный код в плагинах, но это тоже отдельная тема, и в этом вопросе можно без этого аспекта.

**Обновлено:**
Как я пока думаю это делать.

Отнаследовать от React.Component свой класс `PluginableComponent`, в котором будет коллекция подключеных плагинов (будет инициализироваться из репозитория плагинов). Каждый плагин будет иметь доступ к state компонента (будет передаваться через Init плагина), и при вызове любых событий `React.Component` подобные события будут вызываться во всех плагинах.

Теперь самое сложное. Как плагин может модифицировать render. Как пока не знаю, но мысль такая что сначала срабатывает render у самого компонента, потом в плагине вызовется функция onRender и как аргумент передастся html код результата, и потом через DOM манипуляции плагин добавит необходимый HTML в результат. Может быть не очень красиво, но пока не понимаю как иначе сделать. Кроме того как получить HTML код результата render основного элемента пока не знаю.

В результате плагинная система сайта сможет расширять любой элемент сайта объявленный как `PluginableComponent`.

Comment: приветствую! а как вы видете установку этих плагинов? администратор обновляет сайт вручную или юзеры выбирают какие плагины подключить, добавляют код через форму на сайте и смотрят что происходит или как?

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko администратор подключает, конечно в передовой версии просто скачивая и автоматически инсталируя из репозитория, но для начала просто можно скопировать в директорию с кодом и запустить перекомпиляцию

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko я там вопрос обновил, добавил мысли как я думаю это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю стоит следовать традиции реакт приложений и использовать hoc-и для этого. Eсли посмотреть на плагин как на hoc - тогда задача становится не сложнее чем написать оный. Хоки можно объединять в композицию, можно объединять несколько композиций в одну и т.д. хоки могут подменять потомков (children) или оборачивать в некий компонент, могут модифицировать пропсы и т.д.

Библиотека recompose становится очень актуальной при данном подходе.

Чтобы внедрять некий код прямо во внутрь компонента можно предусмотреть некие пропсы в виде скалярных переменных и коллбэков, в которые наш плагин-хок сможет передавать свои значения или функции.

Начал писать код на кодсандбоксе, но к сожалению в данный момент завален текущей работой, однако если интересно, могу вам сбросить прототип такого подходе в течение дня-двух

Comment: а что такое этот hoc? не знаком с этим понятием

Comment: higher order component, по сути это функция, которая получает другой компонент и что-то с ним делает, скажем передаёт некие пропсы, или подменяет компонент другим в зависимости от свох пропсов, довольно универсальная штука. тот же withRouter. В общем это довольно интересная штука, материалов много. В документации и вики к recompose много интересного.  ВОт из текущего проекта: https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/0639c411006a2c506e26b51492c8ac54  , https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/271db281324f95762b671451f6420177 , https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/36c94276cbfa6247f111fbc0fcc68f37

Comment: ого, интересно, я правильно понял что это часть инфраструктуры React? или это не к react относится а к TypeScript?

Comment: кстати в старом api реакта была возможность создавать mixin-ы , но её убрали, так как где-то я читал, что наследовать от react.component не рекомендуется (фейсбуком), а рекомедуется делать композиции из компонентов и хоков

Comment: Это всё простые функции, в тайпскрипте они типизированные (или нет, по желанию)

Comment: больше информации: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=react+hoc&oq=react+hoc+&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j35i39l2.2564j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: да, интересно, при этом как раз мы можем перехватить render метод в hoc-е, получить то что возвратил оригинальный элемент, и сделать необходимые замены в html или что даже ещё круче, некоторые замены прямо в React компонентном коде. То есть наш hoc сначала получает результат render внутренего элемента, делает необходимые манипуляции и возвращает новый  результат. только интересно что возврщает сама функция render... готовый html или React компонентный код...

Comment: функция render возвращает тип React.ReactNode , можете глянуть в тайпингах чему это равно. Конечно, чисто теоретически в хоке можно отрендерить jsx в строку и что-то в ней заменить, вот только как результат отправить далее непонятно. Но даже если и извернуться, это уже не реакт получается, а какие-то хтмл шаблоны. В общем всё зависит от задачи

Comment: он возвращает какую-то структуру с React содержимым, если в ней разобраться, думаю можно будет туда добавлять какие-то дополнительные ноды, или редактировать существующие.

Comment: так как раз думаю красивее будет не в строку содержащию HTML добавлять а в нормальный структурированный React.ReactNode.

Comment: да дело в том, что как такового реакт-содержимого не существует, весь jsx трансформируется в вызовы React.createElement('div', props, context), а реакт компонент это функция которая получается пропсы и вызывает вышеприведённый код.

Comment: тогда нужно будет написать хок - Pluginable Component у него будет коллекция плагинов, каждый будет навешивать что-то на рендер который возвращает предъидущий

Comment: В результате мой плагин будет на разные компоненты через  Pluginable Component добавлять свои элементы)... вообщем похоже понятно как делать, без деталей пока, но суть ясна

Comment: ну да, я хотел пример сделать и скинуть, но оказалось несколько сложнее, чем я сначала думал (типа за 5 минут напишу), однако может позже гляну. https://codesandbox.io/s/1owk2j7jpq там changeBackgroundPlugin работает, а actionPlugin не работает %)

Comment: спасибо за предложеную помощь, я пока сам попробую написать, мне важно разобраться как React работает, но у меня эта задача не на сейчас, я к плагинам думаю только месяца через 2 перейду, пока просто подготавливаю почву. Если ещё с React как оказалось можно решить достаточно просто то с ASP.NET там задача посложнее, и пока до конца не понятно как решать, хотя есть наработки. Но с вами было бы приятно и интересно пообщаться. Мой skype: dmitrij.polyanin (Океаний)